# Workfront API Unknown Object Type

Tags: rest, attask, workfront-api

I'm getting an error when trying to reference different object codes using the workfront API. When I try to do a `https://company.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/arvpth/search`

I get the following response:

`{"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"Unknown object type: arvpth in v2.0"}}`

I know the object code exists because it's in the API Explorer. The only thing that's got me confused is that the error displays v2.0, if this means it's trying to use the API versioin 2.0 then, yes the object code did not exist in that version. So does anyone have an idea on why is it trying to use v2.0 instead of the current v4.0 of the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use v4 of the API, you have to append `api/v4.0/` to your link, ie, `https://company.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/v4.0/arvpth/search`

At least, that is what I had to do in my version of the environment. Hope this helps.

Comment: Aweosome! Thanks for the help! Apparently I got a bad example because I chose one example that gives a different error.

`{"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"ARVPTH is not a top level object and can't be requested directly in internal"}}`

but, at least this one is understandable.

Comment: I've had that happen as well. I think there are only a few top-level objects (task, project, program, portfolio, issue maybe?) that are defined in the Workfront API and those are the things you can reference directly. I might be misremembering, but regardless, whatever those are are the only things you can reference directly. Anything else you have to reference based on a particular top level object.